# MySQL: how can i get the latest datetime together with the other values?

Tags: c#, mysql

```
MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("connection...");
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Select Year,Newsales,Beginninginventory,Purchases,Goodsforsales,Endinventory,Costofsales,GrossIncome,Salesandwages,sss,Rental,Postage,Lightandwater,Freight,Fuel,Officesupplies,Taxesandlicenses,Representation,Depreciation,Transportation,Repairs,Miscellaneous,Totaloperatingexpense,Netincomebeforetaxes,Provisions,Netincomefinal from revenue where Year = select max(Year)", con);
MySqlDataReader reader;
try
{
    con.Open();
    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while(reader.Read())
    {
        this.chart1.Series["Sales"].Points.AddXY(reader.GetString("Sales"),reader.GetInt32("NewSales"));
        this.chart1.Series["Sales"].Points.AddXY(reader.GetString("Cost"), reader.GetInt32("Costofsales"));
        this.chart1.Series["Sales"].Points.AddXY(reader.GetString("Gross"), reader.GetInt32("GrossIncome"));
        this.chart1.Series["Sales"].Points.AddXY(reader.GetString("TotalOE"), reader.GetInt32("Totaloperatingexpense"));
        this.chart1.Series["Sales"].Points.AddXY(reader.GetString("NIBT"), reader.GetInt32("Netincomebeforetaxes"));
        this.chart1.Series["Sales"].Points.AddXY(reader.GetString("NetIncome"), reader.GetInt32("Netincomefinal"));
    }
}
catch(Exception t)
{
    MessageBox.Show(t.Message);
}
```

in my table revenue(sample):
Year         Newsales   Beggininginventory ...... Net income
2015-03-10  83390          30000                   20302.08
2015-03-11  87680          20000                   18680
2015-03-12  105750         30000                   61415.25

desired output:
2015-03-12   105750      30000      61415.25

Comment: In what way is your current SQL statement not doing what you want?

Comment: the select = max() is wrong.

Comment: I see now.  You need to add the `from revenue` after that and put `()` around the sub-query.  Note it would be easier for people to see the issue if you edit the SQL so it isn't one huge line of text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `select max(Year)` by itself is not a valid sub-query.  So change your SQL from

```
Select
    Year,
    Newsales,
    Beginninginventory,
    Purchases,
    Goodsforsales,
    Endinventory,
    Costofsales,
    GrossIncome,
    Salesandwages,
    sss,
    Rental,
    Postage,
    Lightandwater,
    Freight,
    Fuel,
    Officesupplies,
    Taxesandlicenses,
    Representation,
    Depreciation,
    Transportation,
    Repairs,
    Miscellaneous,
    Totaloperatingexpense,
    Netincomebeforetaxes,
    Provisions,
    Netincomefinal 
from revenue 
where Year = select max(Year)
```

to

```
Select *
from revenue 
where Year = (select max(Year) from revenue)
```

Note you don't need to list every column if you want all of them.  Just use `*`.  If there are more columns than what you had listed then go back to listing them.